# Show Qt images on a PHP webpage

Tags: php, qt, ubuntu

Hi I've written a machine vision algorithm on an embedded board using qt environment . it takes webcam images and perform some processing on them. I want to access to the output of my algorithm via a web browser. I'm working in Ubuntu OS and installed LAMP on my board.

I also started to learn PHP to design a web page where I can see the output of my program. but I don't know how I should grab the output images from my qt application and show them on the webpage when I connect to my board, Since these are two different environment with different image architecture (Qimage vs some image structure in php) . How should I do that ? I don't want to save the images into the hard disk and then open these images by php. I want to find the output images in RAM and show them on-the-fly in my web browser ...

What should I do ? I thought of creating some shared memory between my qt application and the web browser but I don't know if it's possible or not !

Thanks

Comment: Don't worry about creating an image class in PHP, just pass the raw bytes through to your web client, preceded by appropriate HTTP headers. The browser will sort out the rest.

Comment: but how !!! how can I pass my images from a ram location to PHP ? I don't know where my images are stored in ram !!!